# About the error in the installation steps of readthedocs local server

Tags: python, read-the-docs

I'm trying to install `readthedocs` on my local gitlab server and I'm following the guide in the link.

[ReadThedocs Guide](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Here's the python version and pip version I'm using;

```
Python3.9 
Pip3.9
```

To run the virtual pip environment, I use the following command.

```
python3.9 -m venv tutorial-env  # I completed the install process with this command. 

source tutorial-env/bin/activate # with this command I access the virtual pip environment
```

my steps in the virtual pip environment;

I run this from the readthedocs installation steps.

```
(tutorial-env) [redhat@gitlab tutorial-env]$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And no error occurred.

```
(tutorial-env) [redhat@gitlab tutorial-env]$ python3.9 /home/redhat/readthedocs.org/manage.py migrate
```

Gave the following error message

```
[debug    ] Using slumber v2.              [readthedocs.api.v2.client] api_host=http://127.0.0.1:8000 username=test

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/redhat/readthedocs.org/manage.py", line 11, in <module>

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/home/redhat/tutorial-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line

    utility.execute()

  File "/home/redhat/tutorial-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute

    django.setup()

  File "/home/redhat/tutorial-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup

    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "/home/redhat/tutorial-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate

    app_config.ready()

  File "/home/redhat/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/core/apps.py", line 15, in ready

    import readthedocs.core.signals  # noqa

  File "/home/redhat/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/core/signals.py", line 17, in <module>

    from readthedocs.core.unresolver import unresolve

  File "/home/redhat/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/core/unresolver.py", line 16, in <module>

    @dataclass(slots=True)

TypeError: dataclass() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slots'
```

However, when I run the `python manage.py migrate` command in the pip virtual environment, I get the following error message and I can't complete the installation process. What exactly this problem points to?

Thank you for support.

I haven't tried any solutions because I don't understand what is causing the problem.

Comment: I doubt you are running "Pip3.9", as that version would not run on Python 3.9. Make sure that you have installed the [requirements](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#requirements). For RH: `sudo yum install python-devel python-pip libxml2-devel libxslt-devel`.

Comment: yes you are right. I solved your problem by installing pip 3.10. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You are following an outdated and unofficial documentation** of Read the Docs (https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). The official guide is a lot more updated and uses Docker now, which is easier to setup. Please, **read the official guide at** https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/install.html